# Getting all row data from minimum value in a field in a SQL query (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, subquery, min

I'm having trouble obtaining a row of all information from a SQL query by specifying the minimum value of a field. Below is a basic example of the data I'm using and what I am trying to obtain:

```
SELECT 1 AS NUM_, 'ABC' AS LET_ FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 2 AS NUM_, 'DEF' AS LET_ FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 3 AS NUM_, 'GHI' AS LET_ FROM DUAL;
```

The query above will yield the following result:

```
NUM_ | LET_
-----------
  1  | ABC
  2  | DEF
  3  | GHI
```

I only want the row that has the data `1` and `ABC`. This is what I tried, below:

```
SELECT MIN(LN.NUM_) AS MIN_NUM, 
       LN.LET_ 
FROM   (SELECT 1 AS NUM_, 'ABC' AS LET_ FROM DUAL
        UNION
        SELECT 2 AS NUM_, 'DEF' AS LET_ FROM DUAL
        UNION
        SELECT 3 AS NUM_, 'GHI' AS LET_ FROM DUAL) LN
GROUP BY LET_;
```

But the above still gives me all of the rows. How do I zero in on just the row with the lowest value in the `NUM_` column, giving me `1` and `ABC`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query finds the minimum `NUM_` for each `LET_`. TO get the minimum `NUM_` for among all the records use `ORDER BY` & `ROWNUM`

Try this

```
SELECT LN.NUM_ AS MIN_NUM, 
       LN.LET_ 
FROM   (SELECT 1 AS NUM_, 'ABC' AS LET_ FROM DUAL
        UNION
        SELECT 2 AS NUM_, 'DEF' AS LET_ FROM DUAL
        UNION
        SELECT 3 AS NUM_, 'GHI' AS LET_ FROM DUAL
        ORDER BY LN.NUM_) LN
Where ROWNUM = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle 12C, you can use the ANSI standard `fetch first row only` syntax:

```
SELECT 1 AS NUM_, 'ABC' AS LET_ FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS NUM_, 'DEF' AS LET_ FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS NUM_, 'GHI' AS LET_ FROM DUAL
ORDER BY 1
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out, there are different ways of doing this:

Some methods:

- `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY`
- `ORDER BY` in view then `ROWNUM = 1`
- (my addition) `MAX KEEP`
- (my addition) Uncorrelated subquery

`FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY` is the easiest syntax, and performs well enough.  But if you have a large table, the other methods deserve consideration as well.

Your data set is too small to demonstrate the different performance results, so to illustrate them, let's create a table out of `DBA_OBJECTS`.

```
create table matt_test as SELECT * FROM dba_objects;
create unique index matt_test_u1 on matt_test (object_id);
exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(USER, 'MATT_TEST');
```

Then, try some different ways and measure each using DBMS_XPLAN:

#### MAX KEEP

```
SELECT MAX (object_id) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY object_id) object_id,
       MAX (object_name) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY object_id) object_name
FROM   matt_test o;

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name      | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |           |      1 |        |      1 |00:00:00.29 |    8522 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE    |           |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.29 |    8522 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| MATT_TEST |      1 |    555K|    555K|00:00:00.12 |    8522 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

#### FETCH FIRST (note the memory usage)

```
SELECT object_id, object_name
FROM   matt_test o
order by object_id
fetch first 1 rows only;

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                | Name      | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |  OMem |  1Mem | Used-Mem |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT         |           |      1 |        |      1 |00:00:00.33 |    8522 |       |       |          |
|*  1 |  VIEW                    |           |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.33 |    8522 |       |       |          |
|*  2 |   WINDOW SORT PUSHED RANK|           |      1 |    555K|      1 |00:00:00.33 |    8522 |  2048 |  2048 | 2048  (0)|
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL     | MATT_TEST |      1 |    555K|    555K|00:00:00.12 |    8522 |       |       |          |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

#### UNCORRELATED SUBQUERY

```
select object_id, object_name
from matt_test
where object_id = ( SELECT min(object_id) FROM matt_test );

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name         | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |              |      1 |        |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       7 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | MATT_TEST    |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       7 |
|*  2 |   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN          | MATT_TEST_U1 |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       6 |
|   3 |    SORT AGGREGATE            |              |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |
|   4 |     INDEX FULL SCAN (MIN/MAX)| MATT_TEST_U1 |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("OBJECT_ID"=)
```

So, you can see an uncorrelated subquery *can* be much faster, if you can take advantage of an index.  The `MAX KEEP` approach performs a little better than the `FETCH FIRST ROWS` approach, in that it uses less memory.

There is no one best approach: each has its place.

If I were writing this without regard to performance (e.g., smallish data set), the default approach would be `FETCH FIRST ROWS`.